# No me encuentra la ruta al dar clic al botón en el patrón MVC

Tags: php, mvc

tengo un problema que no logro resolver con una ruta el contexto es el siguiente.
Estoy tratando de insertar una etiqueta  en un json para que me envíe a otra pagina en el atributo href coloco "estudiantes" y efectivamente de redirecciona a la pagina el problema es cuando trato de agregar "estudiante/" desde este momento el servidor automáticamente me arroja que La URL solicitada no se encontró en este servidor. Cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con rutas amigables en el patrón MVC

Esta es mi lista blanca

```
 $ruta = array();
    if (isset($_GET["ruta"])) {
      $ruta = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);

      //! LISTA BLANCA TODOS LOS ENLCES
      if ($ruta[0] == "inicio" || $ruta[0]== "salir" || $ruta[0]=="perfil" || $ruta[0]== "carreras" || $ruta[0]=="usuarios" || $ruta[0]== "estudiantes") {
        include "modulos/".$ruta[0].".php";
      }
```

y esta es la forma en que estoy tratando de llamar la pagina solicitada, cabe destacar que necesito que me envié a la pagina estudiantes y que en la url vaya el id de esa fila cosa que hace pero NO muestra el contenido

```
$botonesr= "<div class='form-group row' style='display: contents;'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-info' style='margin: 2.5px;'><i class='fas fa-university'></i> Carrera</button><a  class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' style='margin: 2.5px;' href='estudiantes/".$mostrarcarreras[$i]['Id_carrera']."'><i class='fas fa-user-graduate'></i> Estudiantes</a></div>";
```

Adjunto la foto del resultado que obtengo utilizando el codigo anterior
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, el problema es que en la condición no te va a reconocer estudiantes/loquesea, solo te va a reconocer estudiantes porque lo tienes escrito así. Colocaré una respuesta con una manera de trabajar con url's amigables con mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En index.php puedes hacer:

```
if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
    $controller_name = $_GET['controller'].'Controller';
    
    if (class_exists($controller_name)) {
        $controller = new $controller_name();
        
        if (isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controller, $_GET['action'])) {
            $action = $_GET['action'];
            $controller->$action();
        } 
    }
}
```

Aquí concateno 'Controller' porque si estas trabajando con mvc tus controladores terminaran así.
Verifica si existe la clase del controlador y el método y si es así lo llama.
Ya luego desde el método renderizas la view de la página de estudiantes para mostrar lo que sea.

Luego puedes colocar `else` si no se cumple la condición para redirigir a una página de error.

Importante tienes que editar el .htaccess para crear la estructura GET:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Hola jose te comento que viendo tu htaccess a mi me faltaba agg la / en el archivo hice el cambio y funciona muy bien pero se me presento el siguiente inconveniente y es que me redirecciona a la pagina estudiantes pero no me toma los estilos

Comment: ¿Estas incluyendo las views de layouts? Se debe tener en las views un archivo que contenga el header de la web, y ahí va la etiqueta `<head>` con los estilos y demás y es compartida a todas las páginas. Lo que harías sería en el index.php hacer un require 'views/header.php' (por ejemplo) antes de lo de las rutas eso si

Comment: Muchas gracias funcionò perfectamente el archivo htaccess me ayudo mucho me faltaban varios parametros